# How to pre-index a large C project for VSCode C/C++ Extension

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

We have a C codebase which is around 9GB in size! It takes a lot of time (hours) to create the IPCH database/files and hence the intellisence doesn't work so well for the first few hours of the project. 
Is it possible to index the whole project separately and use the resulting IPCH database for all our work spaces.

One more problem is that indexing is done only for those files which are clicked. We want the IPCH to be built for all the files no matter whether they are clicked or not.

We are using "Remote SSH" plugin and the system which we work on are essentially virtual machines but we have a facility of NFS mounts, hence we can mount those pre-compiled ipch stuff to all our virtual machines.

Please suggest the right workflow.